# DocuSign RestApi. Is it possible to change userStatus?

Tags: docusignapi

Im currently trying to change the userStatus from Active to Disabled (for example). 
Im doing it as follows, trying to update the user´s status:

PUT /v2/accounts/{accountId}/users/

```
"users": [{
     "userName": "adrian",
     "userId": "xxxxx",
     "userType": "CompanyUser",
     "isAdmin": "False",
     "userStatus": "Disabled",
     "uri": "/users/d1c408d9-e026-421d-829c-8810b03ba1c0",
     "email": "xxxx@gmail.com",
     "createdDateTime": "2018-07-25T12:46:43.8430000Z",
     "firstName": "",
     "lastName": "adrian",
     "permissionProfileId": "7566819",
     "permissionProfileName": "DocuSign Sender",
     "jobTitle": "Doctor"
}]
```

I got a successful response but afterwards the userStatus does not change.

Does anyone know how to do it?
Thx thx.

Comment: Could you please include the error you are getting?

Comment: I dont get any error, apparently the response says that it´s ok but the userStatus is not changed.